# jquery fadeIn does not reach full opacity on doubleclick?

Tags: jquery, css

I use jquery to load and fade in content in a target div. This works great and i love how neat it looks. However if you click a link to fade in the content several times (fast) the content doesent seem to progress to full opacity. So if i press the link twice (again quite fast) it only reaches like 50% transparancy. Why is this? Can i put like another code wich guarantees this? This is my code:

```
$(".nav").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#target').html('Loading...');

        $.get(this.href, function(data) {

            $("#target").hide(0, function(){
                $(this).html(data).fadeIn("fast");
            });

        }); 
});
```

Comment: can you show your relevant html also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add `.stop(true,true)`

```
$(".nav").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#target').html('Loading...');

        $.get(this.href, function(data) {

            $("#target").hide(0, function(){
                $(this).html(data).stop(true,true).fadeIn("fast");
            });

        }); 
});
```